# Excluding a sub-class from an animation in Jquery/CSS

Tags: jquery, css, joomla

I have a site where by I am using a small jQuery function and css to translate a section on page scroll (fades in and moves up).

All of the sections that I do not want to animate have a sub-class of 'sp-portfolio' i.e. `sp-page-builder .section .sp-portfolio` but the function works on `.sp-page-builder section` See below (please note, this runs in Joomla hence the slightly different syntax at the start:

```
jQuery(document).on("scroll", function () {
    var pageTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop()
    var pageBottom = pageTop + jQuery(window).height()
    var tags = jQuery(".sp-page-builder section")
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var tag = tags[i]
        if (jQuery(".sp-portfolio")[0]){
        //Do Nothing
        } else {
            if (jQuery(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
                jQuery(tag).addClass("visible").delay( 800 )
            } else {
                jQuery(tag).removeClass("visible")
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The css is:

```
/** Animation test **/
.sp-page-builder section:nth-child(n+3):not(:nth-last-child(-n+2)) {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  transform: translate(0, 100px); 
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.sp-page-builder section:nth-child(n+3):not(:nth-last-child(-n+2)).visible { 
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

Is there a way to check if the sub-class **.sp-portfolio** exists and if so to skip the function on that section.

The above code just seems to skip the function on the entire page rather than moving on to the next section.

A sample page can be seen here: [SP Portfolio](https://precision.sitewidehosting.co.uk/) - The sections that should not move are 'Our Work' and 'Latest Insights'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On re-reading I notice that the `.sp-portfolio` class is not on the `section`, but somewhere lower in the DOM tree. In that case easiest would be to just fix your code as follows:

```
if (jQuery(".sp-portfolio")[0]){
    //Do Nothing
} else {
```

Could be rewritten as follows

```
if (jQuery(".sp-portfolio", tag).length){
    //Do Nothing
} else {
```

Specifying the `tag` as second parameter means that jQuery only searches inside that element (aka [context](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)).

---

<strike>You can use the [:not() selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) in the query.</strike>

```
var tags = jQuery(".sp-page-builder section:not(.sp-portfolio)")
```

That way you only get `section`s that do not have class `.sp-portfolio`.

Answer (score 2):

You can test if an element with class `sp-portfolio` exists in JavaScript.

```
if ($(".sp-portfolio")[0]) {
    // Class exists
} else {
    // Class does not exist
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dominik, I'm still struggling to get this to work - obviously, if the class does exist WITHIN the Section I want to skip to the next section, but am not sure how to do that? I have added the if/else in to the existing code but this does not seem to be having an effect. Please see updated code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in a loop with your `if` query and the `if` query should only refer to the current element, this element must also be addressed.

You can easily do this by changing your code

`if (jQuery(".sp-portfolio")[0]){`

in

`if (jQuery(tag).hasClass(".sp-portfolio")){`

Your used code always refers to the first element on the whole web page with the corresponding class, no matter if it is in the loop or not. So if the class exists only once – *no matter where on the page* – the query always returns a `true` and behaves correctly.

With the small adjustment you just refer to the current element in the loop and not to the whole page.

I hope this could help. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).on("scroll", function () {
    var pageTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop()
    var pageBottom = pageTop + jQuery(window).height()
    var tags = jQuery(".sp-page-builder section").not(".sp-portfolio");
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var tag = tags[i]
        if (jQuery(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
            jQuery(tag).addClass("visible").delay( 800 )
        } else {
            jQuery(tag).removeClass("visible")
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

You should use **.not** the function of jQuery which will let you select only those **.sp-page-builder section** element, which doesn't have **sp-portfolio** class.